# Setting a running count for each occurance MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
Jack             8:00 am May 10th
Jack            10:00 am May 10th
Jack             1:00 pm May 10th
Bill             7:00 am May 10th
Bill            11:00 am May 10th
Diane            1:10 pm May 10th
```

Say I have this, is there any way I can set a count for each occurrence. As in Jack would be a 1 for 8 am, a 2 for the 2nd occurrence at 10am and 3 for 1pm. Then Bill likewise, would have his first occurrence be a 1 for 7 am and a 2 for 11am.

So I could then write a case statement if xxx = odd then clock in if xxx= even then clock out or even if xxx= 1 clock in, xxx=2 out, xxx=3 in ect till like 5 since we would never have 5 clock ins and outs in 1 day.

All of our time punches come in straight like displayed, no in or out, we are fixing this in a month or two but for now I would like to assign at least something along these line to it and for the most part people follow a clock in clock out format. If someone forgets, then it is updated by a manager.

In this table there are a few joins and unions, would this be the best option? Or is there an easier way to do it? This is just a sample code.

```
SELECT  Lastname
       ,Firstname
        , Rownumber
  FROM
     (
      SELECT  @row_num := IF(@prev_value=SA.lastname,@row_num+1,1) AS RowNumber
             ,SA.Lastname
             ,SA.Firstname
             ,@prev_value := SA.lastname
        FROM SubAdmins SA,
             (SELECT @row_num := 1) x,
             (SELECT @prev_value := '') y
       ORDER BY SA.lastname DESC) AS Subquery
```

Comment: You mean your query is working? because looks ok to me and and is the way I would do it.

Comment: Step 1. Store dates and times as a single entity, and employing a valid data type.

Comment: I like SQL a lot, but honestly I would do what you're describing in application code. Just fetch the data and apply complex business logic in your application.